# how to display complete file name on choose file button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display the complete file name next to a "*choose file*" button.
The problem is if the file name is too long, it is not displayed. How can I display the complete file name?

[image]

Ex: if the file name I am selecting is `Spring4MVCFileUploadCommonsExample.zip` then after choosing a file it is displaying the name as `Spring4MVC....mple.zip`

If I try to increase the width, the bootstrap panel element expands also.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/uploadAttachementFiles.controller.js"></script>
      <script src="js/uploadAttachementComponent.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uploadAttachementfiles.css">
   <!-- <style>
  .panel-body{
    display: grid; 
   }
   </style> -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mkpApp" ng-controller="mkpUploadController as vm">   
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="desc" class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-form-label">Description:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9">
      <textarea class="btn-block" rows="3" cols="5" maxlength="255" id="desc" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="uplodedFiles" class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-form-label">Uploded Files:*</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Location</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div ng-repeat="file in vm.files">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px" ng-hide="myValue" ng-click="Remove($index)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
              </button>
              <input type="file" value="{{vm.Name}}" id="fg" class="pull-left" />
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="Add()"></span>
            <input type="button" ng-click="Add()" value="Add" ng-model="Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <script>
  var mkpApp = angular.module('mkpApp', []);
  mkpApp.controller('mkpUploadController', ['$scope', function($scope,$window) {
   var file = {};
   $scope.vm.files = [file

   ];
   $scope.Add = function(){
    //Add new item to Array
    var file = {};
    file.Name = $scope.Name;
    $scope.vm.files.push(file);
    //Clear Text boxes
    $scope.Name = "";
    console.log(file);
   };
   $scope.Remove = function(index){
    //Find the record From Array Using index
    {
     //Remove Item from Array using index
     $scope.vm.files.splice(index,1);
     console.log(index,1);
    }
   }   
  }]);
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do much to control the default behavior of the HTML controls, but you can get the name from the value of the file input. Have you tried this? $('#fg').on('change', function() { // get file path var filePath = $(this).val(); // output the path to a separate element $('myDiv').html(filePath); });

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Check this technic It might help you.

```js
$("[type=file]").on("change", function(){
  var file = this.files[0].name;
  var placeholder = $(this).attr("placeholder");
  if($(this).val()!=""){
    $(this).next().text(file);
  } else {
    $(this).next().text(placeholder);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5em;
}
label, input {
  color: #333;
  font: 14px/20px Arial;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-align: right;
}
[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
input,
[type=file] + label {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
[type=file] + label {
  text-align: center;
  left: 7.35em;
  top: 0.5em;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[type=file] + label:hover {
  background: #75397c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="file" type="file" placeholder="Chosse File" />
  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround using javascript

HTML code:

```
 <form>
  <input type="file" id="upload-file"/>
  <label for="upload-file">Upload file</label>
  <div id="file-name"></div>
</form>
```

CSS(To remove default behaviour):

```
#upload-file {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And finally java-script code:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'upload-file' );
var fileNameDiv= document.getElementById( 'file-name' );

input.addEventListener( 'change', showFileName );

function showFileName( event ) {
  var input = event.target;

  // get file name
  var fileName = input.files[0].name;
  fileNameDiv.textContent = fileName;
}
```